# Дефекты локализации обновлённого профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, статус-запланировано, локализация

## Неисправленные [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

**Раздел "Профиль"**

[image]

- Английские названия дней недели и месяцев в календаре дат посещений
- Там же недели начинаются с воскресенья (как принято в Америке), а не с понедельника (как принято в русскоговорящих странах)

**Раздел "Активность"**

[image]

- Не согласующееся с числительными до 20 количество голосов ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/33274/lenovoid?tab=topactivity))  [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

[image]

- На вкладке "Голоса -> восстановление" названия действий на английском  [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

[image]

- Не переведён маркер "recommended" [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

**Раздел "Править"**

[image]

- Placeholder поля "Обо мне" переведён Промтом, а не живым человеком, хоть немного понимающим английский язык.  [статус-запланировано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be)

[image]

- Не согласуются названия месяцев и не переведено слово used в разделе "Доступ"  [статус-воспроизведено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), [нет-в-transfex](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-transfex)
- В сайдбаре "Скрыть Сообщества" с большой буквы, в заголовке - с маленькой (аналогично - "Редактировать Профиль").  [статус-запланировано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be)

[image]

- Не переведены названия кнопок Hide и Unhide в разделе "Скрыть Сообщества"  [статус-воспроизведено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be),  [нет-в-transifex](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-transifex)

## Исправленные

**Раздел "Профиль"**

[image]

- Описание раздела "Скрытые сообщества" в сайдбаре на английском

[image]

- Заголовок раздела "Top Network Posts" на английском

[image]

- Английские названия знаков на вкладке "Профиль" (при этом названия знаков русские на вкладках "[Активность -> Сводка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlJ9Q.png)" и "[Активность -> Знаки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YghU4.png)")

[image]

- Английские подсказки для значков вопросов и ответов в секции "Лучшие сообщения с Меты"

**Раздел "Активность"**

[image]

- Английские названия месяцев в графике репутации
- Английская фраза "N helpful flags"
- Не согласующиеся падежи в трекере прогресса знака по метке (возможный вариант исправления - поменять местами слово и цифры: ответы 91/80)

[image]

- На вкладке "Репутация" слово "Репутация" в заголовке с большой буквы (на остальных вкладках заголовок с маленькой)

[image]

- На вкладке "Голоса" фильтр "восстановить" не согласуется с другими фильтрами ("удаление", "закрытие", "восстановление")

[image]

- Английский заголовок подсказки трекера прогресса знака
- Описания знаков "Любознательный" и "Пытливый ум" вылазят за границы блока
- Часть описаний знаков на английском, часть - на русском
- (*возможно, не сюда*) Расползается вёрстка в нижней части окна

[image]

- Английская подсказка для иконки настройки трекера прогресса знака

[image]

- Не переведено поле "Stack Overflow Careers"

[image]

- Не переведено описание раздела "Новостная рассылка"
- Не переведено описание раздела "Скрыть Сообщества"

Comment: Большая часть этого списка исправлена. Плейсхолдер резюме вынес в отдельный вопрос: [Новый хороший текст для «образцового резюме» участника](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2439). Остальное либо напрямую исправим, либо вынесем в багрепорты в ближайшее время.

Comment: Уже семь лет планируют?

Comment: "Пристав" ой как страшно. Было.

Answer (score 4):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)

При наличии модераторских прав ломается верстка вкладки "Активность":

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: "Очистка через 2 дня" `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Страница изменения информации профиля, вкладка "Редактировать профиль"

Из-за длинной строки у twitter сдвинулось поле ввода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и в русском языке нет традиции начинать каждое слово с большой буквы:
Редактировать Профиль -> Редактировать профиль
Скрыть Сообщества -> Скрыть сообщества